# Regex pattern to replace a local address with a hyperlink address in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string

```
var str = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules"
```

I want to replace the "C:\Program Files\" part with a hyperlink part "https://" so that the final outcome is

```
"https://nodejs/node_modules"
```

The first step to replace the slases with regex I already did it with

```
replace(/\\\\/gi,"/")
```

hence it became

```
"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules"
```

So, the regex for the final outcome ,am facing difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use 2 capture groups:

```
^[A-Z]+:\\(?:[^\\\n]*\\)*([^\\\n]+)\\([^\\\n]+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]+:\\` Match 1+ chars A-Z `:` and `\`
- `(?:[^\\\n]*\\)*` Optional repetitions of any char except `\` ad then match `\`
- `([^\\\n]+)` Capture **group 1** Match optional chars other than `\`
- `\\` Match `\`
- `([^\\\n]+)` Capture **group 2** the same as for capture group 1
- `$` End of string

And replace with

```
https://$1/$2
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uGLt73/1).

```js
const regex = /^[A-Z]:\\(?:[^\\\n]*\\)*([^\\\n]+)\\([^\\\n]+)$/gm;
const str = `C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules`;
const result = str.replace(regex, `https://$1/$2`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have increased one capture size(https://regex101.com/r/QdmA2o/1) , but suppose if the input is only 2 captures required then it don't detect. Is there a way to dynamically output according to the captures.

Comment: @SouvikGuha You might use for example an optional first capture group: `^[A-Z]:\\(?:[^\\\n]*\\)*?(?:([^\\\n]+)\\)?([^\\\n]+)\\([^\\\n]+)$` See https://regex101.com/r/vBNVqO/1

Answer (score 0):

Find

```
^[A-Z]:\/[^\/]+(.*)
```

Replace

```
https:/$1
```